# Distribute iOS app to customers without enterprise account

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

At our company we are developing apps (Android and iOS) for use by other companies. The app (or the right to use the app) is sold together with the server solution (app works with a custom server at that companies' headquarters, that would only work on their network - or VPN) and also a desktop solution that uses the same server. Basically a complete software and hardware solution for use by that company. Payment is made for the whole package, together with maintenance, so selling the app in the store is not a solution.

Is there any way to distribute the app to the customer without them having an enterprise account? (we think it would be difficult to convince clients to pay 300$/year extra just for an app). The simplest solution would be to publish the app on the App Store for free, as it would be useless without the custom server and credentials, could it pass the approval process? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would definitely work as a (free or paid) app on the App Store. Just make sure you have a demo account which Apple can use during the review process (there's a section in iTunes Connect where you can specify credentials for them). You might let the app connect to a different (test) server if somebody logs in with username `info@apple.com`.

Comment: I accept the answer for the moment. Will try this and I will update the question if there is any change. Thank you